# Sql query question finding out table name from sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am testing one of my project it's opencart

Basically i wanna know my table name for sure for example oc20_product and oc20_manufacturer are table names aren't them ? and this the others actual columns ?

What is my table and column name for sure ?

Thanks in advance

Notice:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '%' AND p.status = 1 GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id ORDER BY m.name
>   ASC' at line 4 Error No: 1064

```
SELECT m.manufacturer_id, m.name, COUNT(p.product_id) AS products_total 
FROM oc20_product p 
LEFT JOIN oc20_product_description pd 
ON pd.product_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN oc20_manufacturer m 
ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
WHERE pd.name LIKE '%mycard'%' AND p.status = 1 
GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id 
ORDER BY m.name ASC in
```

Comment: The error message seems very clear, you have syntax error in `'%mycard'%'`, it should be `'%mycard%'`

Comment: Pham thanks for the answer i am well aware of that i just wanna know these are my tables for sure ? oc20_product 
oc20_product_description oc20_manufacturer these are my tables right ?

Comment: Not understand your question. Those are certainly your table, and in your query, those table are using alias, so `oc20_manufacturer` is alias by `m`, and `m.name` means `column name of table oc20_manufacturer`.

Comment: Thanks Pham because i coundn't be sure with colunm_name is name or m.name so if i do sql query like that  "select m.name from oc20_manufacturer " than i will list all manufacturers with m.name isn't it ?

Comment: For table alias you could refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)) or `google: sql table alias`

Answer (score 0):

wrong quote in  like pattern  you could use a concat for an easy pattern format

```
SELECT m.manufacturer_id
    , m.name
    , COUNT(p.product_id) AS products_total 
FROM oc20_product p 
LEFT JOIN oc20_product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN oc20_manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id 
WHERE pd.name LIKE concat('%',mycard,'%') AND p.status = 1 
GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id, m.name
ORDER BY m.name ASC
```